# React state not updating after filtering the data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am making an application that should filter images by their tags using a drop down list. I am initially setting my images in state, and mapping through them to display them. There is also a dropdown list that shows a list of tags a user can filter from. On change of the select box, I am resetting the state to have all the images, then filtering the images, then setting the state again to reflect the new filtered image list. The problem I am having is that when I initially select a filter, it shows me the correct images based on their tag, but when I try selecting another filter, it sets my state to an empty array, even though I am resetting the state to it's original state. Here is the current file I am working with:

```
// Dependencies
import { getTags, getAllImages } from '../../utils/API';
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Components
import EachImageComponent from '../sub-components/Images/EachImageComponent';
import TagsComponent from '../sub-components/TagsComponent';

const GalleryComponent = () => {
    //Set state
    const [allImages, setAllImages] = useState([]);
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
 
    //On first mount, get all the images and tags, and set them in state. 
    useEffect( async () => {
        const response = await getAllImages();

        if(!response) {
            throw new Error('No images to display!')
        }
        
        let data = await response.json();
        setImages(data);
        //Using setAllImages in order to reset state to all images for later use.
        setAllImages(data);

        try {
            // Get all tags and parse them and save them to state for use in the select form
            const response = await getTags();

            if(!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('No tags found!');
            }

            const tags = await response.json();
            tags.unshift({tagName: "All"});

            setTags(tags);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        
    }, []);

    const handleSelectChange = async (e) => {
        // Set the current tag that has been selected in varaibale
        let tag = e.target.value;
        // If selected tag has a value of 'All', then images state to all images for display
        if(tag === 'All') {
            const response = await getAllImages();

            if(!response) {
                throw new Error('No images to display!')
            }
            
            let data = await response.json();
            setImages(data)
        } else {
            // If the selected tag is not 'All' reset state to allImages, then filter the images 
             by tag, then set images to the filtered images
            setImages(allImages)
            let newImages = images.filter(image => image.tags.tagName === tag)
            setImages(newImages)
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
             <select onChange={handleSelectChange} name="tagsIndex" id="tag">
                {tags.map(tag => (<TagsComponent tag={tag} key={tag._id} />))}
            </select>
            <StyledDiv>
                { images.map(image => (<EachImageComponent image={image} key={images._id} />)) }
            </StyledDiv>
        </>
    )

}
```

I am not sure if I am using state here incorrectly but I can not seem to get my state back to it's original form. I am pretty sure this is happening because on the second go around, it is trying to filter and already filtered array, which in turn will return just an empty array, but I am unsure as to why the state is getting reset when I run setImages(allImages) before I filter again. Here is an [image of data I am getting for Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi2yi.png) if this helps any

Comment: The `setImages()` function does not immediately change state. Rather than setting state based on other state, you can store the selected tag in state and show the filtered results based on that tag. If computing the values is potentially expensive, you can use the [`useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook to memoize the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the array every time you choose a value on the dropdown, you have to render the images like so:

```
{images.filter(image => image.tags.tagName === tag).map(image => (<EachImageComponent.../>))}
```

this way you don't have to fetch images each time you change tags, and it also work as expected